# PHP with mysqli loop until condition met. when boolean is 0 to 1 in table page will redirect to other page

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, mysqli, do-while

Here some my code for see if boolean is 1 then go to google.com.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $acc_num = $_POST['acc_num'];
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM security_protocol WHERE acc_num='$acc_num'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $boolean =$row["boolean"];
        if($boolean > 1) {
            $t_slot_times = $t_slot_time + 1;
            for ($i = 1;$i<=20;$i++)
            {
              header("Location: google.com");
             }}}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment yet, so I'll show you what I understood from your question.

There are a couple of things I would like to tell you:

1. You didn't close your `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` statement.
2. Please make your code easier to read.
3. Why do you have a for loop when you don't use `$i` and why does the for loop loop 20 times?
4. Escape the `$_POST` variable or use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.
5. What does `$t_slot_times` store?

Here's what I have for you right now:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $acc_num = $_POST['acc_num'];
    $acc_num = mysqli_real_escape_string($acc_num);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM security_protocol WHERE acc_num='$acc_num'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Go trough the received data
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $boolean = $row["boolean"];

        if($boolean == 1) {
            $t_slot_times = $t_slot_time + 1;

            header("Location: google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

It will be much easier to help you if you could give us more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have done this via AJAX.